# Issues with fetching data from rapid API, using fetch-node

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've copied the demo code off their site but it seems that I can't crack it, I've never got this error, Used double quotes and without quotes on the keys in the post options, still getting this error.

```
const res = await fetch("https://textanalysis-keyword-extraction-v1.p.rapidapi.com/keyword-extractor-text", {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
         "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
         "x-rapidapi-key": "ksjadkasjkasjkfjhjafkakjkajkasjf", // hidden key
         "x-rapidapi-host": "textanalysis-keyword-extraction-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
      },
      "body": {
         "text": "Keyword extraction is tasked with the automatic identification of terms that best describe the subject of a document. Key phrases, key terms, key segments or just keywords are the terminology which is used for defining the terms that represent the most relevant information contained in the document. Although the terminology is different, function is the same",
         "wordnum": "5"
      }
   })
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.headers);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
   });
```

Here is the error, apparently it's something to with `"[Symbol(Body internals)]"` coming out as an empty object

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://textanalysis-keyword-extraction-v1.p.rapidapi.com/keyword-extractor-text',
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }, // error code
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a 404 code indicates malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing.

But everything looks good in the code snippet that you have posted above. Try this:

```
fetch("https://textanalysis-keyword-extraction-v1.p.rapidapi.com/keyword-extractor-text", {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "textanalysis-keyword-extraction-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": ""
    },
    "body": {
        "wordnum": "5",
        "text": ""
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

You can always get in touch with the support team at support@rapidapi.com